# Exporting double value to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, double, export-to-csv

I am trying to export `double` values to a `CSV` file as follows

```
double[] arr = new double[] { 0.0000074, 0.00000123, 0.0000001254 };
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.csv"))
{
    foreach (double item in arr)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(item);
    }
};
```

The output when `CSV` is opened in `Excel/Notepad` is the same and is as follows

```
7.40E-06
1.23E-06
1.25E-07
```

Expecting the output to be same as the input in the `CSV` file. Looking forward to any kind of input/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: The number are the same so why do you care?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could specify the format of the `double` `string` by putting floating-point format like `"F9"`:

```
double[] arr = new double[] { 0.0000074, 0.00000123, 0.0000001254 };
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.csv"))
{
    foreach (double item in arr)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(item.ToString("F9")); //note the F9
    }
};
```

`9` is the amount of number you want to keep after decimal separator (`.`). You could specify the number as you want (for instance `F10`, `F11`, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Save them as string instead for double;

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.csv"))
{
    foreach (double item in arr)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(item.ToString("#.#########");
    }
};
```

For Formatting you can use any of the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
"C", "E", "e", "F", "G", "N", "P", 
"R", "#,000.000", "0.###E-000",
"000,000,000,000.00###"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *represent* a value in some *special format* (e.g. with *leading zeros*) use *formatting*: `String.Format()`. You have no need in `StreamWriter`: put `File.WriteAllLines` and let .Net do the work for you:

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Test.csv", 
    arr.Select(item => item.ToString("F9", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you just need to expand the column width (double click the line between A & B).